# Can you send a message to an email account through an alias in javamail?

Tags: java, smtp, exchange-server, jakarta-mail, alias

Example:

```
Account   account@gmail.com
Alias     ​​account
```

I want to send the message as follows:

```
m_simpleMessage.setRecipient(
    SMTPMessage.RecipientType.TO, 
    new InternetAddress ("account")
);
```

Is it possible to send an email using an alias?

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible send email using an alias?

Assuming that you are talking about some kind of alias defined in Exchange, then I think that the answer is no.  Or at least, not unless your application has the smarts to lookup aliases in Exchange and translate them to real email addresses ... *before* it sets the recipient address.